# What is the present progressive conjugation of "loaf of bread"?

Tags: conjugation, present-progressive

I need to use the phrase "loaf of bread" in the present progressive tense. What is the proper conjugation?

Comment: Let me get this straight:  Are you loafing your bread?

Comment: In the phrase "loaf of bread", both words are _nouns_, so there is no conjugation (no tenses), only declension (one _loaf_, many _loaves_; or the texture of the _bread_, the _bread's_ texture). Loaf, though, is also a verb, but in that case it has a different meaning ([stand or wait in a place, not doing anything interesting or useful](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/loaf)), so you could say you're _loafing around the bakery_ :)

Comment: Crumby grammar strikes again.

Comment: Likely not intended, but the question makes for a good joke. +1

Comment: The poster is perhaps confused by the cockney rhyming slang, in which “loaf of bread” means head. But not as a verb — even for Harry Kane.

Comment: ***I am baking** a loaf of bread.*

Comment: Loaf of breading?